# hot to get the selected text and selectedIndex in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I need to get the selected text and selectedIndex in dropdown on submit..The below code returns the first index always 0 with the first option text..for example if i selected three,it shows 0 index and one text...

```
function myfunc()
 {
    `enter code here`var x = document.getElementById("listt").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("listt").options;
    alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
}
 <select id="listt" >
   <option >one</option>
    <option >two</option>
     <option>three</option>
     <option >four</option>
    </select>

<input type="Submit" value="submit " name="Submit" onclick="myfunc()"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<select id="listt" >
    <option >one</option>
    <option >two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option >four</option>
</select>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="Submit" value="submit " name="Submit" />


function myfunc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("listt").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("listt").options;
    alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
}
document.getElementById ("btnSubmit").addEventListener ("click", myfunc, false);
```